# How to send variable content to a file

Tags: bash

basically, what i am trying to do is delete a line from a file. The user enters a search string then the program searches for everything other than the search string then stores it in the file. Here is my code:

```
elif [ $res -eq "2" ] 
then
     echo "Enter phrase to delete: "
     read -e deletestr
     d=`cat phonebook | grep -v $deletestr`
     echo $d > phonebook
```

When I run the script it always empties the phonebook file. Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure that `cat phonebook | grep -v $deletestr` prints anything?  Have you tested it in the shell?

Comment: Unquoted `echo $d > phonebook` is string-splitting the contents of the `$d` variable on `$IFS`, and passing each word in `$d` as a separate parameter to echo, so even if this otherwise worked correctly, it would have everything all on one line... probably not what you want. `echo "$d" >phonebook`, by contrast, would eliminate this particular flaw.

Comment: Also, the unquoted `$deletstr` used with `grep` could have unintended consequences. Use more quotes. Also, `$()` is much preferred over backticks. If you use single square brackets, you need to quote the variables within. Double square brackets don't need the variables quoted. In Bash, use `elif (( res == 2 ))` for integer tests. Double parentheses don't need quotes or dollar signs on variables and can use comparison operators like `>=` instead of `-ge`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest either creating a *new* file, and replacing the old file after you've done the removal, or using a tool such as `sed -i` that can edit a file *in place*.

Something like:

```
grep -v "foo" phonebook > phonebook.new
mv phonebook.new phonebook
```

Or

```
sed -i '/foo/d' phonebook
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit a file, you can use the editor

```
ex phonebook << DONE
g/$delstring/d
x
DONE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `>>` instead of `>` to append stdout to the file.

If you want to read more about I/O redirection, this is a good guide: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: Actually, I dont want to append. I want to replace all the text with the results of the grep function

Comment: Then redirect to another file, and replace the original phonebook with the new file.